# Filter/Redirect HTTP requests based on URL in Ad-Hoc connection

Tags: windows-7, ad-hoc-network, web-filtering

My computer (Windows7) is connected to the Internet via ethernet, and I shared this Internet connection via WIFI (Ad-Hoc).

Is it possible to filter/block/redirect URLs for specific MAC/IP addresses, for the other computers connected to my Ad-Hoc network?

[image]